# Selenium Webdriver [Java] [gecko] : How do I pass a string to a input field in an Alert

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gecko, geckodriver

I have an online Web Application where there is a product listed which have a View button. On clicking the View button an alert is shown. The Alert have four (4) fields as: Alert Text, An Input Text field, OK button & Cancel button. The Alert text reads as "The Alert Text is :Product is out of Stock ! Please enter your Email Id".

If I Cancel the alert with my Selenium Java code, it works well:

```
//Switch to the Alert & Dismiss
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

If I simply click OK with my Selenium Java code, it does works well:

```
//Click on Accept
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

But if I try to provide my email id in the Input Text field on the Alert,

```
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("debanjan.selenium@mymail.com");
//driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("debanjan");

//Click on Accept
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Selenium is showing org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException as follows:

> The Alert Text is :Product is out of Stock ! Please enter your Email
>   Id org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Missing 'value' parameter
>   (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 6 milliseconds

OS Details: 'Windows 8' pro, os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2',

Java.version: '1.8.0_77'

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Can anyone help me out please?

The weird thing is that:
When I try through standalone Selenium Java Class to  handle the Alert (i.e. passing the emailID in the Alert Text Box) this piece of code works fine.

```
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("debanjan.selenium@gmail.com");
```

But when the same code is implemented through a FRAMEWORK (which I implemented) [Class : PlaceOrder, Method : orderCamera()], the emailID is never written in the Textbox field of the Alert.

Comment: try using Robot to pass value in the alert box if driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("debanjan") doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the email to the specific text field

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
WebElement inputTextField = driver.findElement(...);
inputTextField.sendKeys("debanjan.selenium@mymail.com");
alert.accept();
```

And to switch back

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: I wanted to tryout this approach but neither with Firebug/Firepath nor with xPathCheeker I am able to find out the xpath of the element (i.e. textbox). Any other suggestion?

Comment: @Dev Can you share the website?

Comment: @Guy, are you sure that this code might ever work?  pop-ups triggered by `alert()`, `prompt()`, `confirm()` are not part of `DOM` and thus there is no possibility to select "elements" from pop-up.

Comment: @Andersson The OP didn't mention how the alert is being created, so I thought he/she might check this option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try [driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html#sendKeys-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Yes, I have tried this: <<driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("debanjan.selenium@mymail.com"); >> but it doesn't works for me.

Comment: @Dev This solution work for me. Could you help to check if this is a real alert or a modal with alert look.

Comment: The weird thing is that:
When I try through standalone Selenium Java Class to  handle the Alert (i.e. passing the emailID in the Alert Text Box) this piece of code works fine.

 driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("debanjan.selenium@gmail.com");

But when the same code is implemented through a FRAMEWORK [Class : PlaceOrder, Method : orderCamera()], the emailID is never written in the Textbox field of the Alert.