# How to retrieve the alert text from the newly opened window using Selenium and Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, alert, window-handles

When I click button submit on [that page](http://www.yizhike.com.cn/chou/a.html), it will `window.open()` a new page with an alert.

Does someone know how to get the new page's alert text "got you ?"

Below is my code, but it does not work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\auto\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.yizhike.com.cn/chou/a.html");
    String current = driver.getWindowHandle();
    driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();

    Set<String> handlers = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for (String s : handlers){
        if (!s.equals(current)){
            driver = driver.switchTo().window(s);
            String aa = driver.switchTo().alert().getText(); // **it will take endless time in here**
            System.out.println(aa);
        }
    }
}
```

a.html:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>page a</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function Wopen(){
      window.open('b.html','_blank','width=600,height=400,top=100px,left=0px')
      } 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onClick="Wopen()" value="submit" id="submit"/>
</body>
</html>
```

b.html:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>page b</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("got you!");
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: ie could work fine, but chrome not works, so weired

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text **got you!** from the [Alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063954/selenium-webdriver-java-gecko-how-do-i-pass-a-string-to-a-input-field-in-a) which appears on the [newly opened window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49031048/selenium-switch-focus-to-tab-which-opened-after-clicking-link/49031245#49031245), you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("http://www.yizhike.com.cn/chou/a.html");
String mainWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#submit"))).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
Set<String> allHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
for(String handle:allHandles) {
    if(!mainWindow.equalsIgnoreCase(handle)) {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        System.out.println(driver.switchTo().alert().getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your replay, @DebanjanB , but it seems not work

Answer (score 0):

You given wrong URL: driver.get("http://www.yizhike.com.cn/chou/b.html") in your code. It should be "http://www.yizhike.com.cn/chou/a.html" (parent window URL).

I have also mentioned code below worked for me:

```
    WebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver();
    Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Driver.manage().window().maximize();
    String url = "http://www.yizhike.com.cn/chou/a.html";
    Driver.get(url);
    String current = Driver.getWindowHandle();
    Driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
    Set<String> handlers = Driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> it = handlers.iterator();
    String Parentid = it.next();
    String Childid = it.next();
    System.out.println(Childid);
    Driver.switchTo().window(Childid);*/
    System.out.println(Driver.switchTo().alert().getText());
```

Comment: thanks for your corrections, yes, it should be a.html, but your code dosenot works in my env, and my chrome is 83.0.4103.106, what is the version of your chrome?

Comment: My chrome Version: 74.0.3729.157 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure how it works in IE and not in Chrome, but if i can guess the way they consume JavaScript to load the pages may differ

When i try to read the page Source after switching to the new window it was waiting for the page to complete its load.not sure why..

I tried  to automate using AUTOIT.

```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.yizhike.com.cn/chou/a.html");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    String current = driver.getWindowHandle();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();

    Set<String> handlers = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for (String s : handlers) {
        if (!s.equals(current)) {
            driver.switchTo().window(s);
           //calling AutoIT Script to click ok

            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Muthukumar\\Desktop\\pu.exe";     
           //refreshing the page to get the popup again     

            driver.navigate().refresh();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            String alertText = alert.getText();
            System.out.println("Alert data: " + alertText);
            alert.accept();

        }
    }
    driver.quit();
*******************************************************
AUTO IT Script:
sleep(4000)
$pos=MouseGetPos()
MouseClick("left",478,252,1,0)
MouseMove($pos[0],$pos[1],0)
```